# Fiddler capture c# https request

Tags: c#, https, fiddler

My PC is running two c# application.

I want the one of the C# application go through fiddler proxy that running on My local PC.
and I want the other one C# app go through fiddler proxy that running on remote PC.

I have installed 2 fiddler cert generated by the above two different proxy.
But I found that only the fiddler running on local PC can decrypt the https.

Is is because my PC treat the two cert as one single cert ?
Can make one application trust on one set of cert and the other one trust on another set of certs ?